# Best way to display geometry from SQL Server on a map on a webform

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms, geometry, openlayers-3

I've got a table in SQL Server which contains a few hundred thousand polygons in geometry fields, and need it so that the user can display them on a webform.

The user should be able to query these and, depending on, say, a county field, display all the results. The results may contain 20,000+ results.

I would be worried about speed here. At the moment I'm looking at using OpenLayers.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but I question returning 20,000 of *anything* to a user to do anything meaningful with. If it's just for display purposes, you can use UnionAggregate to, well, aggregate all of those geometry instances into one instance that can be returned/displayed to the user.

Comment: Do you still need help with this?